# When does も mean 'even though'?

Tags: particle-も

I read on Jisho.org that the も particle can mean:

4. even if; even though; although; in spite of​.
   Often as 〜ても, 〜でも, 〜とも, etc.

I was translating「事故だったと言っても」, and I was wondering how the meaning changes. From my current understanding, it could mean:

1. Even if you said it was an accident...
2. You also said it was an accident...

The full sentence is 「事故だったと言っても信じてもらえないんですよね。」("...I would not believe you.")

When can も be taken to mean 'even if'? From the Jisho example, it says ても, and the Japanese quote uses て-form for 言って, with も right after, so does it only mean 'even if' after a て- formed verb?

Comment: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A is one example without the te-form

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/992/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21561/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2056/9831

Comment: `Even if you said it was an accident ... I would not believe you.` <-- I think the subject of "言っても" is "I", and the subject of 信じる is "you" (The subject of 信じてもらう is "I").

Comment: How can one tell which subject goes with each verb?

Comment: @OliverZ. The subject of もらう is always me (or someone related to me). Look up giving-and-receiving grammar.

Answer (score 1):

That entry for も in JMdict (main dictionary of jisho.org) is a little misleading.

J->J dictionaries define ても as its own construct to have the meanings "even if", "even though", among others. The precise formation is

> verb/adjective (連用形) + ても (sometimes でも or っても depending on the verb/adjective)

This is the formation used in the sentence you provided.

Now, it is true that も can also mean "even if", "even though", etc. just like ても -- so JMdict isn't wrong in that sense -- but there's a caveat. The usage of も in this way has different formation rules than ても, and it's an "old-fashioned" style of phrasing according to 明鏡国語辞典 第二版:

> 〘接助〙《動詞の連体形や形容詞の連用形に付いて》…ても。
>   「今日に至るも完成を見ない」
>   「どんなに多くも五人までだ」
>   「遅くも三時までには着く」
>   ▶ 古風な言い方。

Formation for this usage of も is

> [verb (連体形) / adjective (連用形)] + も

---

Side notes:

1. You gave two ways to interpret 「事故だったと言っても」. The first one is possible. The second interpretation is not possible, grammatically speaking.
2. If a person A is the one saying 「事故だったと言っても信じてもらえないんですよね。」, that person A cannot also be the one who could not be convinced that "it was an accident", so you should re-evaluate your "...I would not believe you." translation.